# Prometheus query over a date range

Tags: prometheus

I have the following alert that tells me if a host is running low on memory

`node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 10`

What I would like to know is how to change that query to give me hosts that met that condition in the last two days (and when).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can modify your query by adding instances and jobs. like this!

```
node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes { instance="instance ip", job="node exporter job"}
```

You can select time from the above drag and drop menu as well.

**Method2:**

you can also create variable from dashboard settings.

Comment: I do not know the instance IDs beforehand. This is what I want the query to tell me.

Also, I want to execute this query through both the native Prometheus front end and the REST API.